# How to interpret significant results in adonis, when within group variation is significantly different

Tags: r, vegan

I want to compare community compositions based on a two level environmental factor in `adonis()`, testing significant difference between group `centroids`.
If I apply the adonis function I get significant results, however, I do also get significant results when testing the communities with `betadisper()` which tests differences between within-group variance.

According to Anderson (2002) (R adonis documentation, Notes) it is possible, to get significant results in adonis based on differences in within-group variance.
Is there a way how I can disentangle the two possible reasons for my significances in adonis? Plots do not allow exclusion of one of the possibilities.